# Easylist is incompatible with theorem environment

Tags: theorems, easylist

I noticed that the package "easylist" is incompatible with theorem environment.
Here is an example.
There is unusual space at the left of theorem 1.

Could you fix this strange behavior?

[image: example of easylist and theorem]

This is a source code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
  \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
    @ test
    @ test
  \end{easylist}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `theorem` environment is designed to continue any text on the leadin-line, unless using an explicitly `\par` or a `\leavevmode` command. `\par` does not work for `easylist`, the reason why, `\lipsum` works is an explicit `\par` in its definition (try to load `lipsum` package with the `nopar` option → the lipsum text will start on the header line.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
  \leavevmode
  \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
    @ test
    @ test
  \end{easylist}
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
First
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: quick, "they" will reproach you that `\leavevmode` not being a documented LaTeX command,  it is more kosher to use `\mbox{}`.

Comment: @jfbu: I am reproached by "them" basically for anything I am posting during the last weeks. But thanks

Comment: should we keep our comments visible to "them" ? or rather initiate a secret order ? ... ;-)

Comment: I don't mind keeping them. ;-)

Comment: long live our Bravery !

Comment: I think this does not answer the question, but since it's a bug we can do anything here :-)

Comment: @touhami: Tell the package author ;-) `\leavevmode` or `\mbox{}` works ;-) And as long there's no patch this is a solution, but not the best one, most likely ;-)